# Installing a custom project template with Visual Studio Installer project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, templates, installation

I've created a custom project template, and now I need to deploy it together with my product (i.e., it should be installed by the same msi I use for the main installation). I'm using a Visual Studio Installer project. One option is to use a custom action and manually copy a template file included in the installation. Another is to create a vsi file and use a custom action to install it after the main installation (how do I have it installed silently?) . Which one is better?

Thanks a lot

ulu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In case you are using VS 2005 or 2008**
Just unfold the template files in the proper location for example:
[VSInstallDir]\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesz

**In case you are using VS 2010**
use .vsix The vsix file is the unit of deployment for a Visual Studio 2010 Extension.  Visual Studio will recognize the VSIX extension and install the contents of the file to the right location.

Let me know if you have any questions

s

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended checking for VS versions and copying the files. I target for both 2008 and 2010.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the complete example developing VSIX implemented here: [Multi-Project Templates with Wizard: Visual Studio 2010 Sample](http://vsix.codeplex.com/)